# How do I assign multiple different type of infomation to one name?

Tags: java, data-storage

Sorry If the question was asked wrong, but I am doing a final project in CSP where I want to make a sorting system in Java 1.8.

I have used Hashmaps to store elements in the past, but apparently, they can only store up to 2 elements,
I want to do something along the line of:

```
<String,Double,Int,Int,String>
sortPls.put("Jackson",8.2,12,6000,"A");
```

how do I do it and is there an easier way?

I am using this website called Repl.it, this is my first year coding.

```
public static HashMap<String,Double,Int,Int,String> sortPls= new HashMap<String,Double,Int,Int,String>();
  public static void setList(){
sortPls.put("Jackson",8.2,12,6000,"A");

  }
```

I expected the Hashmaps to hold more than 2 elements, but it returned an error that limits the elements to 2, with the data types after the first 2 being returned as cannot find symbol.

Comment: You need to create a class with fields for each value you want to store. Since you didn't know that, I suggest you progress further in your Java learning, before you attempt to write this code. It won't take long, since classes are one of the first things you'll learn about in Java. If you look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/, it's the 5th section ("Object and Classes"). If you look at [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), it's the 3rd section ("Classes and Objects").

Comment: *"I am doing a final project in CSP"* Don't know what "CSP" is, but it sounds like a course in school, and "final" would mean that you're way beyond where you should have learned about classes, objects, and fields, so I'm down-voting this question. StackOverflow is not a teaching site, and something as fundamental as **objects** in an *Object-Oriented* language like Java, means that you have learned nothing, and should re-take the course.

Comment: CSP means computer science principles which is offered in high school where we were suppose to just learn the basics of logic and introduction to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this

```
public class Data {

    private String name;
    private int val1;
    private long val2;
    private char val3;

    public Data (String name, int val1, long val2, char val3) {
        this.name = name;
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getVal1() {
        return val1;
    }
    public long getVal2() {
        return val2;
    }
    public char getVal3() {
        return val3;
    }
}
```

Using...

```
public static HashMap<String, Data> sortPls= new HashMap(); 
public static void setList(){ 
    Data d = new Data("A",32,12L,'u');
    sortPls.put("Jackson",d);
}
```

Comment: How would i be able to access the infomation in d? I am gonna assume that sortPls.getValue("jackson") does not work

Comment: Example for val2 ................... Data dataSaved = sortPls.getValue("Jackson") ; long j = d.getVal2();

Answer (score -2):

You can still use a `HashMap`, you just need to make the values lists that store your values. Note that I defined the list to hold `Object` data types so that it's most inclusive, but you can change this to hold any data type.

```
   Map<String, List<Object>> data = new java.util.HashMap<>();
   data.put("Jackson", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8.2,12,6000,"A")));

   for (Map.Entry<String, java.util.List<Object>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
       System.out.printf("Entry %s contains:%n", entry.getKey());
       for (List<Object> value : data.values()) {
           System.out.println(value.toString());
       }
   }
```

Comment: That's just so wrong, using a `List<Object>` to store related properties of an "object". With that code, you don't even know what `8.2`, `12`, `6000`, and `"A"` *mean*. The right solution is to create a class with *named* and *typed* fields.

Comment: I gave him an answer that enables him to store his values in a `HashMap`. Yes the class is probably what is looking for, but his whole question is about HashMaps. He could also make a custom implementation of a `HashMap` and do it like that if he really wants to do it with maps, otherwise I agree with you that classes are the best solution here.